# Angular UI router - can't get my data in component after resolve

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-components

I have a router configured like this:

```
.state('home.view-profile', {
    url: '/view-profile/:profileUrl',
    template: '<view-profile input="$resolve.profileData"></view-profile>',
    title: 'View Profile',
    resolve: {profileData: function(artistService, $stateParams){
      return artistService.getArtist($stateParams.profileUrl).then((data) => {
        const timer = new Date();
        console.log(timer.getSeconds() + ':' + timer.getMilliseconds());
        console.log(data.data.artist);
        return data.data.artist;
      });
    }
  }
  })
```

and the component

```
module.component('view-profile', {
templateUrl: 'view-profile/view-profile.component.html',
    bindings: {
      input: '='
    },
    controller: ['$state', '$scope', '$stateParams', function ($state, $scope, $stateParams) {
      const model = this;
      console.log('***************');
      console.log(model.input);
   }]
});
```

I could see that `data.data.artist` is valid and accessible from the log during resolving process, but inside the component the `input` is always `undefined`
J just don't understand why is this happening?

Comment: maybe you should inject `$resolve` to your controller

Comment: I tried, but it has no any meaningfull data on it..

Answer (score 1):

sorry and thanks for your help!
I just found out out the issue. The version of the ui-router was downgraded somehow during our multi-devs workflow. Some of the developers installed `0.2.1` instead of the latest `0.3.x`, i merged and that was the problem.
Only `0.3.x` router supports sending `$resolve.param` to component bindings.
 After upgrading - everything works fine. Only my self-confidence is harmed...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried resolving the promise in the controller?

```
model.input.then(function(res) { console.log(res); }
```

Comment: nope, that didnt work... cannot find provider profileData

Comment: Duh. I was too quick and didn't look through your code well enough to see you were passing things around. Try resolving the promise in the controller to see if that works.

Comment: I could, but as model.input is 'undefined', and I'm sure about it, it will through an error...